# Iframe document global

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

This is the first js/HTML problem I have came across in months that I haven't been able to find an answer for online. If I am dynamically filling an iframe using jquery or plain JavaScript, (so I guess same origin as the parent document), and I fill the child iframe with some script In the body that uses the "document" global - IE "$(document).ready", how I can I ensure it accesses the child document as opposed to the parent? If I fill a dynamic iframe with the following HTML:

```
<iframe id='if'><iframe>
```

And added the following function in a script tag:

```
$(function () {
    var innerDoc = $($('#if').contents()[0].childNodes[0]);
    innerDoc.html("<scr" + "ipt>" + 
      "var h1 = document.createElement('h1'); " + 
      "h1.innerText = 'hi!';" +  
      "document.body.appendChild(h1);" +
    "</scri" + "pt>"); 
});
```

The HTML will get inserted into the body of parent document. I have determined this is because the 'document' variable in the script tag that is being dynamically inserted into the iframe is reference the parent document. How do I ensure that exact statement will execute correctly, as in, the 'document' variable will reference the document of the child iframe?

Comment: You're going to have to show more code that you have. [**This method**](http://jsfiddle.net/o24dqssx/) works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently using the open() and writeln() will make it work as expected - i don't why though.

```
 var iframedoc = $('#if').contents()[0];
 iframedoc.open();
 iframedoc.writeln("<html><head></head><body><scr" + "ipt>" + 
  "var h1 = document.createElement('h1'); " + 
  "h1.innerText = 'hi!';" +  
  "document.body.appendChild(h1);" +
"</scri" + "pt></body></html>");
iframedoc.close();
```